# Trucks fuel economy dependence on weather

Tags: fuel-consumption, truck, weather-dependent

I am searching scientific data and studies on the link between weather and fuel consumption in HDV (heavy duty trucks). 
For now I have found almost nothing.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I can tell you that any combustion engine will produce more power when inducting cool air, slightly moist and ideally as close to sea level as possible.  The reason for this is to do with the amount of oxygen contained in a fixed volume of air is greatest in these conditions.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for as it's not limited to trucks but there's [this](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/9713/Min_Jing.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y)?

Comment: There is material about how humidity changes affect combustion and therefore power output, start by looking for people like Judge, Ricardo and Cummins... It would be useful to understand what and why you are asking as what is relevant may not be limited to trucks...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about motor vehicle maintenance, repair or supporting knowledge domain

Comment: @Zaid so the question about how fuel consumption is affected by the changes to the air entering into the engine in terms of temperature, humidity etc you consider to be off-topic... I would suggest that it should be very **on** topic...

Comment: @Solar Mike I could find nothing of the authors you suggested

Comment: search fail then : https://www.amazon.com/Internal-Combustion-Engines-Classic-Reprint/dp/1330251067

Comment: also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Ricardo

Comment: and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clessie_Cummins

Comment: They have written or have books written about them that I found interesting from lots of angles....

Comment: Comment by @Steve Matthews says it best. Also remember that the fuel formulation is seasonally adjusted by the refiner/distributor.